# Slick Slider extra margin/padding top

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Have run into an issue with slick slider I have never seen before and cannot figure it out myself. The slides seem to be pushed down slightly from their container making them appear outside it and I cannot work out what is causing it. See screenshot: [image: screenshot of margin problem]

Anyone got any ideas on what's causing this weird behaviour? I have searched through all my code for any hidden margins or paddings that may be causing this and had no luck.

Live site [here](http://dev.searsdavies.co.uk/castlebrooke/demo/option1/manchester.html). You can see this strange behaviour on the top and bottom sliding sections but not the middle one for some reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, please include code if possible or better still create a fiddle - secondly, where on your site?

Comment: Ok, had a look, there are 4 slides so no middle one and they all render fine here in Chrome

Comment: I included the link to the whole site as there are many scripts and files at work here that could have been causing the problem. I was talking about the  sliders not the individual slides within them, there are three on the page currently, one with large landscape images, one with graphics and text and one with square images that displays 2 at time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `position:relative;` to `position:absolute;` style.css line 306.

```
    .slick-slider .slick-prev {
        left: 50px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: this fixed it, thanks so much! would never have realised that was the issue